# Who is pissed off here?

Tags: sentence-meaning, attachment-ambiguity

Jack walks up to the girl at the bar and starts flirting, but the girl just looks at him weirdly and walks away. Enjoying this, Ethan grins at Jack, pissing him off.

My question is about the last sentence. Is it clear that Ethan grins at Jack which pisses Jack off?

Comment: That's what it says.

Comment: It's just a ***pragmatic assumption*** that it's ***Jack*** who's pissed off (syntactically, the referent of ***him*** is ambiguous). So in for example, *Ethan gives all **his** money to Jack, leaving **him** without his bus fare home*, we only know ***his*** and ***him*** refer to Ethan because the utterance wouldn't make much sense if either or both of those pronouns referred to Jack.

Comment: It makes no sense to say that Ethan grinned, which pissed Ethan off. If he's old enough to be in a bar, he'd have learned not to do it.

Comment: It's Jack who was pissed off.

Comment: The two uses of ing that way ain't great style.

Comment: How would you write it instead?

Answer (score 1):

In the last sentence, you have two participle forms of verbs (*enjoying*, *pissing off*) which must coordinate with another verb and subject in the sentence. *Ethan grins* is the only source for coordination, so we can assume Ethan is the subject doing the *pissing him off* phrase.

Since Ethan is the do-er of the action, if *him* referred to Ethan, we would also need to see *pissing himself off* in order for the statement to reflect back on Ethan. Since it only has *him*, and not *himself*, the reader can assume it's not Ethan, and must be the other male entity, Jack.